# Allow users to make yes/no decisions using checkboxes

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, javascript

I'm looking for a way my users can interact with my scripts. I'd like to use checkboxes to work like a "yes/no" command, where the script does "A" if the checkbox is ticked, and "B" if the checkbox is NOT ticked.

Problem is, I can't get my head around the syntax of the "if" statement. I can do fine in Google Sheets, but not so much in Google Script, and I need a Script solution.

Any help out there?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do exactly on checkbox press?

Comment: The script that I have in mind has two major parts, and acts on a sheet used as a template.The script is set to actuate by trigger every Friday. The first part of the script runs, doing what scripts do, then the second part of the script runs to reset the template. Some of my users want to reset the template on Friday, while others want to reset the template on Monday. How can I use a checkbox and if statement combination as a "yes/no" command to the script - tick the checkbox to reset the template on Friday, and leave the checkbox alone (unticked) to reset the sheet on Monday? Andy

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications! If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/129735)

Answer (score 0):

To add to Rubén's answer, below I've listed a function that shows how you could retrieve whether checkboxes in a particular range are checked or not.

```
function checkbox() {
   for(var row = 1; row <=10; row++){
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(row,2);
    if (range.isChecked()) {
      // do something
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
  };
}
```

The 2 in the `getRange` function specifies the column.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script uses JavaScript. The syntax for if statement is

```
if (condition) statement;
```

For more details please read

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/conditionals